# Convert string to varbinary - Comparing the two

Tags: c#, sql-server, varbinary

I need to covert a string to a varbinary(85), which is the data type in my SQL Server Table (unable to change). The data is for a username and I need to compare the windows user name of a person who logs onto a website with this SQL data entry. An example of a login that I have in my database is:

0x0105000000000005150000004CCDD8292B55E7A8CD006C0E061F0012 which is the of the datatype varbinary(85).

Now I need to compare this to a string. What is the best way for me to convert a string to varbinary(85) so that I can get the exact same value.

I would preferably do this all in C# although I guess I could do it on the database end in SQL.

ANSWER:

using sql I could generate the name perfectly.

```
SELECT SUSER_SID(string)
```

Comment: This looks like a hashed entry. What algorithm is being used to hash it? It's not just a simple `select convert(varbinary(85),name)` that's for sure.

Comment: Not Completely sure. It's a Microsoft Product (SCVMM) so possibly SHA-256? And ya I've tried a bunch of stuff like that to no avail

Answer (score 0):

1) I would create an [unique] index on `varbinary(85)` column:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IUN_Users_UserName 
ON dbo.Users (UserName) -- Where UserName is varbinary(85)
```

2) I would convert current user name to `varbinary(85)` using the same algorithm

```
DECLARE @binCurrentUserName VARBINARY(85);
SET @binCurrentUserName = .... convert here the current user name to VB(85) ...
```

and I would compare only `varbinary` values:

```
SELECT u.UserID
FROM dbo.Users u
WHERE u.UserName = @binCurrentUserName -- Please remember that UserName's type is VB(85)
```

Note: converting the `varbinary` values from `UserName` column to string (`nvarchar`) it's a bad idea because the SQL query will look like this

```
SELECT u.UserID
FROM dbo.Users u
WHERE CONVERT(... u.UserName ... ) = @nvarcharCurrentUserName
```

and because will be a function (ex. `CONVERT`) applied on `UserName` column this will block `Index Seek` => the execution plan of this query will contain an `Index Scan` operator.

Comment: Just found out how I could do it! By browsing builtin functions. Thanks for the info tho.